# Tendermint: how to change RPC IP of light node

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

I try to implement light node. When starting it up, RPC is always 127.0.0.1:8888. Thus I cannot connect this node from anywhere else.
I also tried to change the ip in the configuration file, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to change RPC IP?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use flag --laddr tcp://192.168.1.49:8811 when starting light nodes.